# Deriving higher-order function in Scala

Tags: scala, higher-order-functions

There are two very similar methods and I am trying to extract a higher-order function out of it in Scala.

1. One way:

   ```
   def delete(userId: String) = {
     val entries = dao.getEntriesForIds(dao.getXXX(userId))
     dao.deleteRef(entries, userId)
   }
   ```
2. Another way:

   ```
   def delete(userId: String) = {
     val entries = dao.getEntriesForIds(dao.getXXX(userId))
                       .filter(_.actorId != userId)
     dao.deleteRef(entries, userId)
   }
   ```
3. My refactored version, which doesn't seem to be a higher order function:

   ```
   def delete(userId: String, **filter: Boolean**) = {
         val entries = dao.getEntriesForIds(dao.getXXX(userId))
         **if (filter)**
             entries.filter(_.actorId != userId)
         dao.deleteRef(entries, userId)
       }
   ```

How can I make this a higher order function ?

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name, since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: There is dedicated [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) forum. You may get more responses there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g.

```
def delete(userId: String, predicate: Entry => Boolean) = {
  val entries = dao.getEntriesForIds(dao.getXXX(userId)).filter(predicate)
  dao.deleteRef(entries, userId)
}

// use 1
delete(userId, _ => true)

// use 2
delete(userId, _.actorId != userId)
```